# Kiel esprimi moviĝon de unu flanko de objekto, kiu troviĝas super vi, al la alia flanko?

Tags: prepositions, phrase-requests

Mi serĉas esprimon por la jena tipo de transa moviĝo.

Estas du aŭtovojoj: unu pasas per ponto super la alia. Vi veturas sur la malpli alta vojo. Kiam vi preterpasas la ponton, vi unue iras sub ĝin kaj poste plu iras de sub ĝi. Do la aŭto veturas de unu flanko de la ponto al la alia flanko (transverse/orte, ne laŭ la direkto de la ponto) kaj kiam vi preterpasas la ponton, la ponto estas super vi. Kiel esprimi tion? Ĉu vi veturas trans sub la ponton? Ĉu vi veturas sube trans la ponton?* Ĉu vi veture pasas sub la ponton?

Simile, imagu, ke vi kuras en arbaro kaj preterpasas branĉon. Dum vi pasas la branĉon, ĝi estas rekte super vi. Ĉu vi tiam kuras trans sub la branĉon? Kiel diri tion?

Tria ekzemplo. Estas fermita pordo kun breĉo inter ĝia suba flanko kaj la sojlo. Vi ŝovas paperon tra tiu breĉo. Ĉu vi ŝovas paperon trans sub la pordon?

Do la ĉefa demando estas: **kiel esprimi la moviĝon de unu flanko al alia de iu objekto, kiu troviĝas super vi dum vi pasas?**

---

Analoge: Se vi ĵetas pilkon de unu flanko de barilo al la alia flanko, ĉu la pilko ĵetiĝas trans super la barilo? Ĉi tie *super* fakte ne necesas, ĉar la ĵetado jam klarigas, kiel la pilko transiras la barilon, sed tio ne gravas; temas pri la sama gramatika afero.

*Mi mem interpretus tion jene: Vi transiras la ponton en la normala direkto de la ponto, sed laŭ ĝia suba flanko anstataŭ laŭ ĝia supra flanko. Do kiam estas ponto super rivero, vi transpasas la riveron per la suba flanko de la ponto, ne de per la supra flanko (kiel normale). Sed mi volas esprimi, kiam vi preterpasas la ponton veturante sur tiu rivero.

Comment: Mi afiŝis ankaŭ en [Kiel oni diras…?](https://www.facebook.com/groups/483836138811235/permalink/949743515553826) kaj tie kelkaj respondis, ke por ili la konstruo ‘trans sub …n’ estis tuj komprenebla kaj senproblema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vi povas uzi `preter`. Ĝi montras tiun movon ĝenerale. El PIV:

```
Prep., montranta objekton aŭ lokon, en kies
proksimeco iu aŭ io pasas, irante plue
```

Se vi uzas `preter` prefikse vi povas aldoni alian prepozicion por klarigi kiel okazas la movo. Jen ekzemplo, el Tekstaro:

```
preteriri antaŭ la princo
```

kiun vi povus modifi jene:

```
preteriri sub branĉo
```

Comment: Jes, la prepozicioj ne estas simetriaj. "Sur" signifas tuŝante kaj "super" netuŝante, sed "sub" povas signifi ambaŭ.

Comment: Tamen oni povas uzi ilin simetrie kaj diri `malsuper`. Kaj en situacioj kiel tiu de la demando, mi pensas ke estus pli klare.

Comment: Povas esti, sed tiam vi devas iel montri, ke vi limigas la vorton "sub" signifi nur la malon de "sur", t.e. tuŝante.

Comment: Iom ironie vi prave rimarkigis al marcus, ke “kuri sub ponto” signifas, ke la kurado okazas plene sub la ponto, dum via propra sugesto baziĝas sur la sama mispenso: se vi pluiras sub ponto, ne estas indiko, ke vi forlasas la ponton… Simile pri _preteriri sub branĉo_: vi preteriras [ion nemenciitan] kaj la preterirado okazas sub la branĉo.

Comment: @Joffysloffy, en `preteriri antaŭ la princo` (Kabe) la preterirata afero estas ankaŭ tiu menciita poste. Saman konstruon vi trovos en `Kiam mi preteriris antaŭ unu el tiaj barakoj` (Zamenhof) aŭ en `Mi malrapide preteriris apud la pordo kaj rigardis internen.` (Löwenstein) aŭ en pluraj aliaj, ekde Zamenhof ĝis nun. Do via analizo ne kongruas kun la fakta kaj daŭra uzo, surbaze de kiu mi skribis mian respondon.

Comment: @EduardoTrápani Mi pli serĉis la legis en tekstaro, kaj mi tute koncedas. Vi pravas. Oni pravige povas interpreti ĉi-tiele: _oni preteriras [la lokon, kiu troviĝas] sub la branĉo_. Tio fakte havas sencon kaj estas malpli peza konstruo, ol ‘trans sub …n’. (Mi devis fari nesignifan ŝanĝon al via respondo, por ke mi povu ŝanĝi mian voĉdonon.)

Comment: @Joffysloffy mi forigis la duan parton de la respondo, ĉar vi pravas, `pluiri sub ponto` kaj `kuri sub ponto` estas similaj.

Answer (score 2):

La verbo "[pasi](https://vortaro.net/#pasi_kdc)" signifas

> Iri de unu loko al alia, ne restante ie

Ĉar vi veturas preter la ponto, vi [preterpasas](https://vortaro.net/#preterpasi_kdc) la ponton. Tiu esprimo ne malkovras, kie vi estis, kiam vi pasis.

Por montri ke la ponto estas super vi, oni povas diri "mi estas sube de la ponto" (rigardu [PIV](https://vortaro.net/#sube_kdc)).

Do mi kombinus tiujn al

- Vi preterpasas sube de la ponto.

Comment: Hmm, _preter_ ja estas bona sugesto. Tamen tiu kombino ne sonas tute bona al mi, ĉar nun ne esprimiĝas tio, _kion_ vi preterpasas, kaj ŝajnas, ke la preterpasado de nemenciita afero okazas plene sub la ponto. Sed tio verŝajne estos bone komprenata.

Comment: Do ŝanĝu al “Vi preterpasas la ponton sube”.

Comment: La preterpasata afero estas tiu menciita poste, ofte ankaŭ subkomprenata. Almenaŭ tion faris pluraj verkistoj. Jen ekzemplo Zamenhofa (estas multaj tiaj, ĉe multaj verkistoj): `kaj [mi] preteriris antaŭ la bieneto de mia mastro`. Se oni ne mencias la preteriratan aferon, ĝi estas tiu, kiun oni enkondukas poste per prepozicio.

Answer (score 1):

Vi bone klarigis tion, kion vi celas diri. Mi provos simpligi vian celon jene:

*Mi veturas trans la ponton* (mi iris al la alia flanko de la ponto)
*Mi veturas preter la ponto(n)* (mi ne atingis la ponton, mi nur preterpasis ĝin).

Sed vi pasas *sub* la ponto kaj vi pasas *transverse*.
Bedaŭrinde *trans* subkomprenigas *super* aŭ *sur*; kaj *preter* subkomprenigas *flanke de*. Sed kun sufiĉe da kunteksto, mi pensas ke neniu el tiuj kromaj signifoj misgvidos vian alparolaton.

Mi opinias ke vi devas elekti prepozicion por la ĉefa senco kaj por la resto uzu verbon (ekz.: pasi) aŭ verban prefikson (ekz.: preterpasi) aŭ alian frazeron (ekz.: sub ĝi, transpasante ĝin, ktp.). Ekzemple:

**Mi preterveturas trans la ponton.**

**Mi preterpasas la ponton sube.**

**Mi preterveturas la ponton sube kaj transverse.**

**Mi preterveturas la ponton, transpasante sub ĝi.** (ĉi tie “transverse” estas subkomprenata, ĉar *preter*, *trans*, kaj *pasi* jam donas sufiĉe da klarigoj por esprimi ke vi ne iras laŭ la direkto de la ponto).

Ne tre plaĉas al mi la kombinaĵon “trans sub” pro la jenaj kialoj:

- Ĉu vi veturas trans sub la ponton?

Mi ja komprenus tion neformale, sed per pura logiko mi legas “trans sub la ponton” kvazaŭ “trans [sub la ponto]”, tio estas “al la alia flanko de la suba parto de la ponto”. La fakto ke tiu diraĵo enhavas “sub la ponton” povus signifi ke la fino de la movo estas sub la ponto, do mi opinias ĉi tiun dirmanieron tre konfuza.

Se oni ŝanĝus la ordon, tio *ne* multe helpus: “sub trans la ponto” aspektas kiel “sub [trans la ponto]”, tio estas “sub la alia flanko de la ponto” kaj tio ankaŭ ne estas la intenco.

- Ĉu vi veturas sube trans la ponton?

Mi ŝatas tiun, sed kiel vi mem diris, mankas la transverseco de la movo. Tio solveblas kun “preterpasi” aŭ “transverse”.

- Ĉu vi veture pasas sub la ponton?

Mi ŝatas tiun, sed mi ne uzus akuzativon. Mi dirus

**Mi veture pasas sub la ponto.** (ankaŭ eblas *transpasi* kaj *preterpasi*).

- Ĉu vi tiam kuras trans sub la branĉon?

Ĉu ne sufiĉas diri jene?

**Mi kuras sub la branĉoj.** (*trans* estas subkomprenata ĉar probable ekzistas multaj branĉoj super oni)

Vi nur bezonas klarigi pli detale se vi diras tion al roboto aŭ en matematika problemo. Tiuokaze estus tute normale aldoni “geometriajn” vortojn kiel “transverse”, “orte”, ktp.

- Ĉu vi ŝovas paperon trans sub la pordon?

Bonŝance pordoj estas pli simplaj ol pontoj kaj malmultaj miskomprenoj povas okazi. Ne eblas iri laŭ la direkto de la pordo. Laŭ mi, sufiĉas “sub la pordon” ĉar la situacio estas preskaŭ evidenta. Krom se oni povus pensi ke la papero restas sub la pordo kaj ne transpasas ĝin. Tiuokaze mi pensas ke vi povas diri:

**Mi transpasigas paperon sub la pordon.**

**Mi transŝovas paperon sub la pordon.**

Comment: Se vi kuras sub la branĉoj, ne estas translokiĝo, vi ĉiam restas tie. Komparu kun la Krestomatia (el mia memoro) _la muso kuras sub la lito_.

Comment: Klarigo aldonita al la respondo. Oni povas resti sub la branĉaro kaj pasi multajn branĉojn tie. Se tio ne sufiĉas, oni povas uzi la aliajn ekzemplojn.

Comment: Ĉu mi diris absurdaĵon por ricevi “-1”?

Comment: Ne, ne estas bone voĉdoni sub nulon.

Answer (score 0):

`Trans` ĉi tie estas evitinda pro sia asociado kun `super`.
Logike estus:

- `subpasi` / `subpasigi` (leteron)

Kvankam rara vorto, mi jam uzis la jenan nocion

- `subpasejo` = passage souterrain [fr] / underpass [en] / Unterführung [de]